# Reconfigure root and postmaster mail recipient in Exim

Tags: dpkg, email, exim

I installed Exim and mailutils (For receiving) for sending mails through PHP in Ubuntu. After I installed it, I ran the command `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, I was asked to set the mail recipient for root and postmaster (I was in a rush). I entered root there (not sure if I made a typo). the next time I try to reconfigure Exim, I am not able to set that one setting. How can I set that setting again? Please let me know. I am not able to find the solution for this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Changing Exim aliases (postmaster,root)

Check and modify `/etc/aliases` (text) file.

Pretty standard procedure is to redirect:
* `postmaster` to `root`
* `root` to non privileged (non root) account of preson acting as root

Comment: I just found the answer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-ubuntu-user-email-address, and you posted the answer as well, lol. What a coincidence.

Comment: I personally prefer another SMTP/MTA server but it is a pretty standard configuration for almost all SMTP/MTA servers on Unix/Linux. It is a part of "sacred ancient legacy of sendmail(.org)" :-)